# EPOLL and starvation of incoming stream

Tags: linux, curl, pthreads, epoll

I have a project which i am converting from the normal select() but due to a test I ran which had over 1000 connections I decided to change this to epoll.

I have the code working but have run into a problem which I am trying to work out which is the best way to fix.

The system has a libcurl thread pulling data from an external source, this is cached in memory awaiting pullers connecting and taking the data.

All is well when the source data is complete, but when someone connects whilst I am downloading new data and they are fast enough to catchup with the libcurl thread, they get into a state of starvation.

My question is how do I restart the pullers without setting the EPOLLOUT and having the epoll_wait constantly telling me there is space in the buffer.

My choices are

1. EPOLLOUT, will cause lots of epoll_waits to tell me the buffer is empty until there is some data available.
2. Timer, how do i decide the delay
3. Have a list of connections and when new data comes in send data from the libcurl thread, which I did not want to do.
4. some kind of signal from the libcurl thread to the epoll loop, HOW?

Any other ideas

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `eventfd()` file descriptor to allow the downloading thread to wake up the epolling thread when more data has arrived.

It's not clear why you didn't have to solve the same problem in your `select()` implementation, though.

Comment: 2048 max sockets without messing around. And reading a few threads about epoll scales up better. Heres hoping

Comment: @JulianGardner: Sure, I understand why you would choose to use `epoll()` over `select()`, but what I'm asking is why you didn't have the same issue with the uploading threads catching up to the downloading threads in the `select()` implementation?

Comment: I did but i used a small timeout on the select to overcome this, same as would happen if i kept EPOLLOUT set all the time.

Comment: Ok code updated, I know have 2 lists, one for sockets that have stalled and another for sockets that have been evenfd_write on them.

In the curl thread loop, i walk this list and post with eventfd_write and move it to the 2nd list:

In the main eventfd loop i check the socket number against this list and if set i go into the send code.